# Retrieve the previous object linked to a form in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form to edit an address for an user (I pass an entity address to the form). When I modify the address and submit the form, I would like desactivate (with a setActive function) the entity that I passed (without new values) and create a new line with new values. Is it possible ?

Example :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$client_adr = $em->getRepository('EcommerceBundle:ClientAdresse')->find($id_adr); // here it's the entity that i want disable

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($client_adr)
        ->add('prenom', TextType::class)
        ->add('nom', TextType::class)
        ->add('adresse', TextType::class)
        ->add('lieu_dit', TextType::class)
        ->add('complement', TextType::class)
        ->add('code_porte', TextType::class)
        ->add('cp', TextType::class)
        ->add('pays', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Modifier'))
        ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
$adr = $form->getData(); // here it's the entity with new values
$em->persist($new_adr);

$em->flush();
}
```

In this example, if I modify the name of my entity, I want that my object "$client_adr" keep its previous values and be disabled (if i call setActive by example) and I want that my object $new_adr be saved on a new line in database with modified values.

Thanks

Comment: Please, show us a code sample to cover the question, this help to answer quickly ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Right after finding your object but before setting in form, `clone` your object then set the `id` null. You may have to add a `setId` method in your entity class.

```
$client_adr = $em->getRepository('EcommerceBundle:ClientAdresse')->find($id_adr);
$clone_adr = clone $client_adr;
$clone_adr->setId(null);
$client_adr->setIsActive(false);

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($clone_adr) ...

....

$em->persist($client_adr); // save old, inactive
$em->persist($new_adr); // save new.

$em->flush();
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! Just one thing : I'm not oblige to unset the ID because clone do it for me

Comment: I have always had to unset the `id` field. `clone` doesn't know that `id` is my primary key.